# Redux enhancer and applyMiddleware

Tags: redux

So, I'm checking out redux codebase,

To create a store, we're calling the createStore function exposed by redux,

```
createStore(ourReducer,{}, applyMiddleware(someMiddleware));


export default function createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) {
  if (typeof preloadedState === 'function' && typeof enhancer === 'undefined') {
    enhancer = preloadedState
    preloadedState = undefined
  }

  if (typeof enhancer !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof enhancer !== 'function') {
      throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.')
    }

    return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)
  } ...
```

In createStore function above, enhancer is called in this part, which is also the applyMiddleware function that I passed on the first line...

```
enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)
```

But when I checked the applyMiddleware function, there are 3 parameters 
(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer)...

```
export default function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {
  return (createStore) => (reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) => {
```

...

It's basically always undefined right? I'm just curious why it's there or if I'm missing something.

```
enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this one comes up (surprisingly) frequently.  It's a holdover from the "old-style" way of using `createStore`.  See [Redux issue #2128](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/2128) for discussion and history as to why that argument exists.